# Sentry add User to Group

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I've already used this library and I cant quite find the problem. For some reason when I'm trying to add a user to a group I get the following MySQL error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users_groups.users_id' in 'field list'

Which obviously means that the field does not exist, I ran this command

```
php artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry
```

And the `users_groups` table is created with just `user_id` && `group_id`, so I don't know where and why it would try to get users_id.

Answer (score 1):

So I found out why, my model class for the config file was named Users, so I'm guessing that's where it get the 'users_id' when trying to save to that column.

Previous:

```
'model' => 'UAQ\Models\Account\Users',
```

Fixed it:

```
'model' => 'UAQ\Models\Account\User',
```

Comment: Models should always be named in the singular form.

Comment: I had the same problem, thanks for adding the answer after finding the solution :)